# How do I Insert All Tables in Database1 into Database2 on different hosts

Tags: mysql, data-synchronization

I want to insert data into database2 on host2 from database1 on host1.
Is there any way to achieve this in PHP?

Comment: Is it a website, cause you could always define 2 hosts and run the update, delete and inserts on both.

Comment: Have you considered replication?

Comment: It is a website running on local machine

Comment: I've tried replication unsuccessfully

Comment: are the hosts on different networks? e.g. one on local network and one on internet host somewhere? You need to make the situation a lot clearer, as it could affect potential solutions.